# Inline custom styles in Microsoft Word

Tags: ms-word, styling

I am using Word for Mac 2011 and I try to define a custom style which I want to apply on **single words** or **parts of a paragraph** among my document. But it seems to me that there is only whole paragraph styles. So if I define my new style, let's say underlined and a yellow background, the whole paragraph is directly set to this style.

Anyone know, how to approach this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ok, I just found out:

*Select text* > Format > Style > New

Then select "Character" instead of "Paragraph" for the option "Style type".

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing today, but in Word for Windows (Office 365 version)

The solution is the same but the steps towards it are different:

1. Select the inline text
2. Open the Styles Pane and press the New Style button (left button on the bottom row)
3. "Character" is now an option for "Style Type"

Comment: Thanks! If you write code in text document, you can even add a shortcut key. I've used CTRL+ALT+Right_arrow